# how can i do my jquery hover functions in one line function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to shorten my code. You can see the following code i used many function for addClass, removeClass. But it is not usefully. Can do my work in one hover function ? If yes can anyone help me ?

HTML

```
<div class="GvStarContainer">
  <!--Style 1 STARTED-->
  <div class="GvStarTmp">

    <div class="margi-star">
      <div class="rate-ex1-cnt">
        <div id="1" class="star star-one-1 rate-btn star-one"></div>
        <div id="2" class="star star-one-2 rate-btn star-one"></div>
        <div id="3" class="star star-one-3 rate-btn star-one"></div>
        <div id="4" class="star star-one-4 rate-btn star-one"></div>
        <div id="5" class="star star-one-5 rate-btn star-one"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--Style 1 FINISHED-->
  <!--Style 2 STARTED-->
  <div class="GvStarTmp">

    <div class="margi-star">
      <div class="rate-ex2-cnt">
        <div id="1" class="star star-two-1 rate-btn star-two"></div>
        <div id="2" class="star star-two-2 rate-btn star-two"></div>
        <div id="3" class="star star-two-3 rate-btn star-two"></div>
        <div id="4" class="star star-two-4 rate-btn star-two"></div>
        <div id="5" class="star star-two-5 rate-btn star-two"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--Style 2 FINISHED-->
</div>
```

JS

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.star-one').hover(function() {
       $('.star-one').removeClass('rate-btn-hover');
       var therate = $(this).attr('id');
       for (var i = therate; i >= 0; i--) {
          $('.star-one-' + i).addClass('rate-btn-hover');
       };
    });
    // Red
    $('.star-two').hover(function() {
       $('.star-two').removeClass('rate-btn-hover');
       var therate = $(this).attr('id');
       for (var i = therate; i >= 0; i--) {
          $('.star-two-' + i).addClass('rate-btn-hover');
       };
    });
    // Pink
    $('.star-tree').hover(function() {
       $('.star-tree').removeClass('rate-btn-hover');
       var therate = $(this).attr('id');
       for (var i = therate; i >= 0; i--) {
          $('.star-tree-' + i).addClass('rate-btn-hover');
       };
    });
    });
```

This is my Demo page: **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VKorea)**

I have still tryed to shorten my code from this demo but it is not working like first demo. **[DEMO2](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/XjvMBg)**

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question is too broad for Stack Overflow as there isn't really a single "correct" answer, but it would be a good candidate for [codereview.se].

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qaexVv

Comment: @DaniP your code is so nice but there is just one problem. When you click 5 star then click 3 star it is not changing.

Comment: Check this now http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ozKEyr

Comment: I'd use the answer below (toggleClass()). But I must say, what you have here is pretty slick :)

Comment: @DaniP Yes not that is working fine but please look at this page you can see what is the new problem. [DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/vXoZXy) . When you hover stars repeating css animation

Comment: @j08691 Thank you [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/145843/how-can-i-do-my-jquery-hover-functions-in-one-line-function)

Comment: @DaniP Dear Please look at this demos. I have created this demo for good understandable problem. [Demo1](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/GjVxvv) no problem with hover animation. [Demo2](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/ozKqwx) problem hover animation.

Comment: @zzzzBov I also asked my question from Code Review but not have any answer.  [QUESTION HERE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/145843/how-can-i-do-my-jquery-hover-functions-in-one-line-function)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been cross-posted on a better suited Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I would say is that you could be using `toggleClass()` instead of using add and remove in conjunction. This shortens your code somewhat. Also, try to be consistent with using single or double quotes. Pick one style and roll with that :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var prevStars = $(this).prevAll();
  var nextStars = $(this).nextAll();

  $(".star").hover(
    function() {

      var prevStars = $(this).prevAll();
      prevStars.toggleClass("rate-btn-hover");
    }
  );

  $("body").on("click", ".star", function() {
    var prevStars = $(this).prevAll().addBack();
    prevStars.toggleClass('rate-btn-active');
  });

});
```

Comment: Can you check this for me Dear. [CLICK](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/145843/how-can-i-do-my-jquery-hover-functions-in-one-line-function)